# How to export mysql database into ms access using php

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

I am looking for a way to export a mysql table into MS Access file using php. The server is windows based and I want to export all the data in my mysql table into a msaccess file. I know about mysql to csv to mbd conversion(using phpmyadmin and ms access s/w), but is there a easy and better way to convert the tables into access file say on a mouse click **using php**?
*Please note that there are lots records in the mysql table*
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can't you just go into your phpMyAdmin and Export the table as a CSV, then import it into Access? Unless **you** write a script that does everything you want at the _click of a button_, I don't think you're going to find a magical button that does it for you.

Comment: I am doing it for a company. They cant always export the table as csv then import it into ms access. There might be some way to program it in php. Yes I am expecting a "Magical Button" solution here.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  I'd probably just connect Access directly to the MySQL DB as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access.html#connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables).  I'm assuming, though, that this is not an option for you.

Assuming you can't do that for whatever reason you can always put together a script to connect to both the MySQL and MSAccess databases via PHP+SQL.  [This link](http://phpmaster.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/) has a guide to connecting to an Access DB via PHP.